# I am trying to export images from a SQL Server 2014 table stored in a varbinary(max) column with SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, image, ssis, sql-server-2014

I am trying to export images from a SQL server 2014 from datatype varbinary(max) with SSIS

I am flowing the example from this website https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2693/export-images-from-a-sql-server-table-to-a-folder-with-ssis/

I all works for me, I ‘am successfully exporting the image to a folder – BUT I ‘am not able to open the image in Paint, I get the error “Paint cannot read this file, or its format is not currently supported”

I don’t ‘know the original format (jpeg, png … or whatever) of the file…

How will I be able to view the just exported image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no builtin functionality in ssms .

You need to use stream writer using any programing language 
ie C# /java / python or power shell

some sample links.

https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/217419/how-to-insertretrieve-image-in-sql-server-database

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c4535b53-30d2-4a5c-a018-0dea7117d34c/saving-an-image-from-sql-server?forum=winserverpowershell